# Flatten a list of nested lists in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

I'm working on the exercises in *Erlang Programming*.

The question is

> Write a function that, given a list of nested lists, will return a flat list.
>
> > Example:
> >     `flatten([[1,[2,[3],[]]], [[[4]]], [5,6]]) ⇒ [1,2,3,4,5,6].`
>
> Hint: use `concatenate` to solve `flatten`.

And here is my `concatenate` function

```
%% concatenate([[1,2,3], [], [4, five]]) ⇒ [1,2,3,4,five].
concatenate([X|Xs]) -> concat(X, Xs, []).
concat([X|Xs], T, L) -> concat(Xs, T, [X|L]);
concat([], [X|Xs], L) -> concat(X, Xs, L);
concat([], [], L) -> reverse(L).
```

I really want to know an elegant way to implement `flatten`. I've spent hours solving this exercise.

**UPDATE**: I forget most important prerequisite. Is it possible solving this problem with only *recursion* and *pattern matching*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would try this way

```
flatten(X) -> lists:reverse(flatten(X,[])).

flatten([],Acc) -> Acc;
flatten([H|T],Acc) when is_list(H) -> flatten(T, flatten(H,Acc));
flatten([H|T],Acc) -> flatten(T,[H|Acc]).
```

testing

```
my:flatten([[1,[2,[3],[]]], [[[4]]], [5,6]]).
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**UPD:** or this way, without guards and reverse, only recursive calls and pattern matching.

```
flatten(X)               -> flatten(X,[]).

flatten([],Acc)          -> Acc;
flatten([[]|T],Acc)      -> flatten(T, Acc);
flatten([[_|_]=H|T],Acc) -> flatten(T, flatten(H,Acc));
flatten([H|T],Acc)       -> flatten(T,Acc++[H]) .
```

Comment: Is it possible solving this problem with only recursion and pattern matching?

Comment: The hint totally misled me. Thank you!

Comment: Using `++` is inefficient as it copies the whole list.

Comment: @rvirding thats correct. That is why in real life a would prefer first variant. But as exercise ++ is ok.

Answer (score 6):

Some different solutions, getting smarter and smarter:

```
%% Lift nested lists to the front of the list.
flatten1([[H|T1]|T2]) -> flatten1([H,T1|T2]);
flatten1([[]|T]) -> flatten1(T);
flatten1([E|T]) -> [E|flatten1(T)];
flatten1([]) -> [].
```

or

```
%% Keep a list of things todo and put tails onto it.
flatten2(L) -> flatten2(L, []).

flatten2([H|T], Todo) ->
    flatten2(H, [T|Todo]);
flatten2([], [H|Todo]) -> flatten2(H, Todo);
flatten2([], []) -> [];
flatten2(E, Todo) -> [E|flatten2(Todo, [])].
```

or

```
%% Work from the back and keep a tail of things done.
flatten3(L) -> flatten3(L, []).

flatten3([H|T], Tail) ->
    flatten3(H, flatten3(T, Tail));
flatten3([], Tail) -> Tail;
flatten3(E, Tail) -> [E|Tail].
```

These are all with only pattern matching and recursion, but they can be improved with some guard type tests. Using `++` is inefficient as it copies the list every time. The `lists` module uses a version of the last one with a guard type test instead of the last clause.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1131941/419206). So when should I use ++ operator?

Comment: And now I think use list comprehension and ++ operator to implement quicksort is not a good idea :(

Comment: @Vayn what you should try and avoid is to append elements to the end of a list with `++`, or any other way for that matter. Appending is not the best operation on a list. Joining two lists together is a another matter. One way of getting around it is to carry around a tail as in my third example.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty concise and straightforward version:

```
append([H | T], L) -> [H | append(T, L)];
append([], L) -> L.

flatten([[_|_]=H|T]) -> append(flatten(H), flatten(T));
flatten([[]|T]) -> flatten(T);
flatten([H|T]) -> [H|flatten(T)];
flatten([]) -> [].
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was about to supply this solution myself after seeing that other solutions use ++ in a bad way.

Comment: @DanielLuna, append is equivalent of ++

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus: neither `++` nor `append` is problem but **use in bad way** is. I'm applying `append` with traversal of flattened head but you are using it to growing `Acc` which is simply terribly wrong. I think it is wrong even for exercise.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil 1) without context it just doesnt make any sense to count cpu ticks -it's just premature optimization. 2) But if you want to count ticks - just trace your and my program for example for data [1,[2,[3,4,5]]], and you'll see that ++ invokes 5 times with short data, and your append() invokes 9 times (including cases with full list). And 3) (last but not least) -- nice nickname :-)

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus I think you are still missing most important think what's wrong with your usage of `++`. For `[1,[2,[3,4,5]]]` input there are 9 calls to append but each of this call makes only one list cons. Only two of this 9 calls are from `flatten`, rest is internal calls within `append`. Your 5 `++` calls are all within your `flatten` function and they makes 11 cons!. It is 9 mine cons vs. 11 yours. Every time you write `Acc ++ [H]` there is something wrong because left operand of `++` grows. Each invocation makes more and more cons.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus I think I found way how demonstrate how bad it is. For input `[1,2,3,4,5]` mine code doesn't call any `append`. Your code calls `++` five times and makes 10 cons. With `lists:seq(1,100)` it would be 100 `++` invocations which makes 4950 cons! Mine code makes 100 cons at all. In short, your code has quadratic complexity.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus Yes, I'm well aware that `append` and `++` are the same. As Hynek is mentioning, it is *use in a bad way* that is the problem.  Quadratic versus linear complexity.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus: Programming rule #1: Don't make stupid things.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil and  it's a pretty stupid thing to count clock ticks in this kind of task. If you disagree, and dont understand difference between 'erlang language' (which is this question about) and 'pecularities of erlang VM implementation' then  http://goo.gl/CAM3j

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus: Implementing something in quadratic way when you easily can do ti in linear is simply stupid thing. It is not about counting clock ticks, it is about algorithms and has nothing common with _'pecularities of erlang VM implementation'_.

Answer (score 2):

concatenate/1 as defined in the book works as a flatten function which flattens down only one level.  (`[[1],[2]]` becomes `[1,2]`, `[[[1]],[[2]]]` becomes `[[1],[2]]`, etc.)  The strategy suggested in the hint is to flatten completely not by defining new logic in flatten/1 but by using concatenate/1 in flatten/1's recursive calls.

```
concatenate(Ls) ->
    reverse(concatenate(Ls, [])).

concatenate([], Acc) ->
    Acc;
concatenate([[]|Rest], Acc) ->
    concatenate(Rest, Acc);
concatenate([[H|T]|Rest], Acc) ->
    concatenate([T|Rest], [H|Acc]);
concatenate([H|T], Acc) ->
    concatenate(T, [H|Acc]).

flatten(L) ->
    flatten(L, []).

flatten([], Acc) ->
    Acc;
flatten(L, Acc) ->
    Concatted = concatenate(L),
    [Non_lists|Remainder] = find_sublist(Concatted),
    flatten(Remainder, concatenate([Acc, Non_lists])).

find_sublist(L) ->
    find_sublist(L, []).

find_sublist([], Acc) ->
    reverse(Acc);
find_sublist(L = [[_|_]|_], Acc) ->
    [reverse(Acc)|L];
find_sublist([H|T], Acc) ->
    find_sublist(T, [H|Acc]).

tests() ->
    [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8] = flatten([[1,[2,[3],[]]], [[[4,[4]]]], [[5],6], [[[]]], [], [[]], [[[7, 8]]]]),
    [1,2] = flatten([[1,2]]),
    [1,2,3] = flatten([[1],[2],[3]]),
    [1,2,3,4,5,6] = flatten([[1,[2,[3],[]]], [[[4]]], [5,6]]),
    tests_successful.
```

Answer (score 0):

The question's key is "divide and conquer".

Another extra function "lists:reverse" and an operator "++" are used for saving programing time.

my_flat([],Result)->
    lists:reverse(Result);
my_flat([H|T],Result) when is_atom(H) ->
    case T of
    []-> 
        my_flat([],[H|Result]);
    _Else ->
        my_flat(T,[H|Result])
    end;
my_flat([H|T],Result) when is_number(H)->
    case T of
    []->
        my_flat([],[H|Result]);
    _Else ->
        my_flat(T,[H|Result])
    end;
my_flat([H|T],Result) ->
my_flat(H,Result)++my_flat(T,[]).

for your test: test:my_flat([[1,[2,[3],[]]], [[[4]]], [5,6]],[]).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, no accumulator and with Erlang list append operation (++):

```
flatten([[_|_]=R | Tail]) -> flatten(R)++flatten(Tail);
flatten([V|Tail]) -> flatten(V)++flatten(Tail);
flatten([])->[];
flatten(V)->[V].
```