# How to extract a list of proplists {K,V} from any complex Term

Tags: erlang

Having a Term that may consist of **anything** such as orddicts, lists of orddicts, orddicts of orddicts, list of lists, proplists of orddicts or ... such as:

```
Term1 = [ 
      {"AAA", [ 
               { "K1", "ka1" },
               { "K2", "ka2" }, 
               { "K3", "ka3" } 
              ]
      },
      {"BBB","one"},
      {"CCC", [ 
               { "K1", "kb1" },
               { "K2", "" }, 
               { "K3", "kb3" } 
              ]
      },
      {"DDD", [ 
                [
                 { "K1", "kc1" },
                 { "K2", "kc2" }
                ],
                [
                 { "K1", "kd1" },
                 { "K2", "kd2" }
                ],
                "CACETA",
                123
              ]
      },
      {"EEE", [ 
               { "K1", "kb1" },
               { "K2", 1122  }, 
               { "K3", "kb3" } 
              ]
      },
              { "T1", "T2", "T3" },
              123,
              { "X" },
              [ 1, 2, 3, { "K5", "V5" } ] 
],
```

I would need to produce a **list of all proplists [{K,V},...]** such as

```
[
   { "AAA" , [ ...... ] },
   { "K1"  , "ka1" },
   { "K2" , "ka2" }, 
   ...
   { "BBB" ,"one"},
   { "CCC" , [ ... ] },
   { "K1"  , "kb1" },
   ...
   { "K5", "V5" } 
]
```

- notice that there are keys that must repeat along the list, their value may be a string, a list, a tupple or number, anything.
- the last items in the data in the example above, such as { "T1", "T2", "T3" } should not be in the result since it is not a proplist of two terms { K, V}, but the nested **{ "K5", "V5" }**  is and should be part of the result.

I looked at this similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344785/flatten-a-list-of-nested-lists-in-erlang) and tried to tune it up a little bit, but it is getting hard for my novice erlang brain to get it to work with my scenario above.

Here is an **example** of what I am trying to use to make it work, but there are some errors, pattern matching related:

```
extractPropList( [], ResultList ) -> ResultList;

extractPropList( [H|T], ResultList ) -> extractPropList(T, extractPropList(H, ResultList));

extractPropList( {K,V}, ResultList ) -> [ {K,V} | extractPropList(K, extractPropList(V, ResultList)) ].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While testing the above approach, the missing part was the last row that treats a term that had no other matching ( not a list, not a {K,V} ):

```
extractPropLists( [], ResultList ) -> ResultList;
extractPropLists( [H|T], ResultList ) ->    extractPropLists(T, extractPropLists(H, ResultList));
extractPropLists( {K,V}, ResultList ) -> [ {K,V} | extractPropLists(K, extractPropLists(V, ResultList)) ];
extractPropLists( T, ResultList ) -> ResultList.
```

Given data similar to the avove, the results I obtained where

```
[{"EEE",[{"K1","kb1"},{"K2",1122},{"K3","kb3"}]},
 {"K3","kb3"},
 {"K2",1122},
 {"K1","kb1"},
 {"DDD",
  [[{"K1","kc1"},{"K2","kc2"}],
   [{"K1","kd1"},{"K2","kd2"}],
   "CACETA",123]},
 {"K2","kd2"},
 {"K1","kd1"},
 {"K2","kc2"},
 {"K1","kc1"},
 {"CCC",[{"K1","kb1"},{"K2","kb2"},{"K3","kb3"}]},
 {"K3","kb3"},
 {"K2","kb2"},
 {"K1","kb1"},
 {"BBB","one"},
 {"AAA",[{"K1","ka1"},{"K2","ka2"},{"K3","ka3"}]},
 {"K3","ka3"},
 {"K2","ka2"},
 {"K1","ka1"}]
```